# Copy cells from one sheet, paste into a second sheet in the correct place based on a VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, vba

I have a submission form, Sheet1, and a datasheet that does calculations, Sheet2. Sheet2 contains a list of Names and Dates and empty cells ready to be filled.

On Sheet1, the user selects a Name from a list in A2 (using data validation, with the source being a 3rd reference sheet), then enters values in C1, D1, E1, F1, etc. The user then clicks a button that prints the form sheet, Sheet1.

I also want to also transfer the data from C1, D1, E1 etc into Sheet2, and slot them into the correct row, which is which ever row has the corresponding Name  entered in Sheet1!B1 in Sheet2!A1.

I'm comfortable with VBA copying defined cells to other defined cells, but am unsure of how to combine that with finding the correct position in Sheet2 based on the value in A. Below are Sheet1 and Sheet2.

[image: Sheet1]
[image: Sheet 2]

Comment: You could just iterate on Sheet2 A1:A[lastrow] and find the correct staff_name and then use that row to copy the rest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please modify to suit your requirement

```
Sub copyrange()

Dim sheet2_row As Integer

sheet1_name = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 2).Value
sheet2_row=WorksheetFunction.Match(sheet1_name,Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A10"), 0)

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2:AG2").Copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & sheet2_row & " : AF" & sheet2_row).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```